# Tracking MongoDB execution times using PHP

Tags: mysql, mongodb, php

I am currently working on a project using `PHP`, I have done research and found that `microtime()` helps with tracking the time of a query in a `MySQL` database..

how do I do the same for `MongoDB`, I have a `PHP` interface and I have also inserted data into the `MongoDB` database using this but how do I show how long the time of the query took to insert into the database.

PHP uses microtime()
MongoDB uses ????

Answer (score 1):

As per MongoDB BOL [Analyze Query Performance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/) usees The [cursor.explain("executionStats")](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#cursor.explain) and the  [db.collection.explain("executionStats")](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#db.collection.explain) methods provide statistics about the performance of a query. This data output can be useful in measuring if and how a query uses an index.

`db.collection.explain()` provides information on the execution of other operations, such as db.collection.update().

Comment: Thank you for the reply, how do I add it to my code so it shows the results when I search the database using the php page


,$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db=$m->CSV;
$mObj=$db->Schools->find()->explain('executionStats');

//foreach($mObj as $oneElement) {
//foreach($oneElement['Street'] as $comment) {

foreach($mObj as $row) {

echo $row['Street'];
echo $row['Town'];
echo $row['Postcode'];


}